# USB to Serial Port

Tags: matlab, usb, serial-port

I bought I device which is to be connected to computer through USB. I am about to program this device using Matlab. I would like my computer to see this device (when connected)as in a communication port not as a usb device. Device manager sees it as "libusb" with USBasp driver.

What I want is to convert its connection as in COM port, so that in my program I can easily declare what COM port is the device connected then I can write/read the data on it.

Comment: You must get windows to list it as a COM port or Matlb won't recognize it. I have used hardware rs232-to-usb hardware dongles (with its associated driver) and got the thing working. Other than that, Matlab can't read directly from a usb port. Thus, you need a hardware usb converter.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jorge. I am currently looking for usb-to-serialport converter.

Comment: I've used several different brands of USB to Serial converters from radioshack and they worked fine. Sounds like you dont have the correct driver installed. Try visiting the company's website and downloading their latest driver.

Answer (score 1):

When I worked at Honda we frequently used these with pretty good success.

http://www.cablestogo.com/product.asp?cat_id=101&sku=26886